# How to test/validate the vmalloc guard page is working in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, stack-overflow

I am studying stack guarding in Linux. I found that the Linux kernel **VMAP_STACK** config parameter is using the guard page mechanism along with *vmalloc()* to provide stack guarding.
I am trying to find a way to check how this guard page is working in Linux kernel. I googled and checked the kernel code, but did NOT find out the codes.

A further question is how to verify the guarded stack.
I had a kernel module to underrun/overflow a process's kernel stack, like this

```
static void shoot_kernel_stack(void)
{
    unsigned char *ptr =  task_stack_page(current);
    unsigned char *tmp = NULL;


    tmp = ptr + THREAD_SIZE + PAGE_SIZE + 0;
//  tmp -= 0x100;
    memset(tmp, 0xB4, 0x10); // Underrun
}
```

I really get the kernel panic like below,

```
[ 8006.358354] BUG: stack guard page was hit at 00000000e8dc2d98 (stack is 00000000cff0f921..00000000653b24a9)
[ 8006.361276] kernel stack overflow (page fault): 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
```

Is this the right way to verify the guard page?

Comment: Which stacks are you speaking about ? This mechanism is for kernel side stacks not for user space side.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I am checking the kernel side stack. And want to know how the guard page is setup and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **VMAP_STACK** Linux feature is used to map the kernel stack of the threads into VMA. By virtually mapping stack, the underlying physical pages don't need to be contiguous. It is possible to detect cross-page overflows by adding guard pages. As the VMA are followed by a guard (unless the **VM_NO_GUARD** flag is passed at allocation time), the stacks allocated in those area benefits from it for stack overflow detection.

**ALLOCATION**

The thread stacks are allocated at thread creation time with *alloc_thread_stack_node()* in *kernel/fork.c*. When **VMAP_STACK** is activated, [the stacks are cached](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/9/16/178) because according to the comments in the source code:

> vmalloc() is a bit slow, and calling vfree() enough times will force a TLB
> flush.  Try to minimize the number of calls by caching stacks.

The kernel stack size is THREAD_SIZE (equal to 4 pages on x86_64 platforms). The source code of the allocation invoked at thread creation time is:

```
static unsigned long *alloc_thread_stack_node(struct task_struct *tsk, int node)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
    void *stack;
    int i;

[...] // <----- Part which gets a previously cached stack. If no stack in cache
      // the following is run to allocate a brand new stack:

    /*
     * Allocated stacks are cached and later reused by new threads,
     * so memcg accounting is performed manually on assigning/releasing
     * stacks to tasks. Drop __GFP_ACCOUNT.
     */
    stack = __vmalloc_node_range(THREAD_SIZE, THREAD_ALIGN,
                     VMALLOC_START, VMALLOC_END,
                     THREADINFO_GFP & ~__GFP_ACCOUNT,
                     PAGE_KERNEL,
                     0, node, __builtin_return_address(0));
[...]
```

__*vmalloc_node_range()* is defined in *mm/vmalloc.c*. This calls __*get_vm_area_node()*. As the latter is not passed the **VM_NO_GUARD** flags, an additional page is added at the end of the allocated area. This is the guard page of the VMA:

```
static struct vm_struct *__get_vm_area_node(unsigned long size,
        unsigned long align, unsigned long flags, unsigned long start,
        unsigned long end, int node, gfp_t gfp_mask, const void *caller)
{
    struct vmap_area *va;
    struct vm_struct *area;

    BUG_ON(in_interrupt());
    size = PAGE_ALIGN(size);
    if (unlikely(!size))
        return NULL;

    if (flags & VM_IOREMAP)
        align = 1ul << clamp_t(int, get_count_order_long(size),
                       PAGE_SHIFT, IOREMAP_MAX_ORDER);

    area = kzalloc_node(sizeof(*area), gfp_mask & GFP_RECLAIM_MASK, node);
    if (unlikely(!area))
        return NULL;

    if (!(flags & VM_NO_GUARD)) // <----- A GUARD PAGE IS ADDED
        size += PAGE_SIZE;

    va = alloc_vmap_area(size, align, start, end, node, gfp_mask);
    if (IS_ERR(va)) {
        kfree(area);
        return NULL;
    }

    setup_vmalloc_vm(area, va, flags, caller);

    return area;
}
```

**OVERFLOW MANAGEMENT**

The stack overflow management is architecture dependent (i.e. source code located in *arch/...*). The links referenced below provide some pointers on some architecture dependent implementations.

For x86_64 platform, the overflow check is done upon the page fault interruption which triggers the following chain of function calls: `do_page_fault()->__do_page_fault()->do_kern_addr_fault()->bad_area_nosemaphore()->no_context()` function defined in *arch/x86/mm/fault.c*. In *no_context()*, there is a part dedicated to **VMAP_STACK** management for the detection of the stack under/overflow:

```c
static noinline void
no_context(struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long error_code,
       unsigned long address, int signal, int si_code)
{
    struct task_struct *tsk = current;
    unsigned long flags;
    int sig;
[...]
#ifdef CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
    /*
     * Stack overflow?  During boot, we can fault near the initial
     * stack in the direct map, but that's not an overflow -- check
     * that we're in vmalloc space to avoid this.
     */
    if (is_vmalloc_addr((void *)address) &&
        (((unsigned long)tsk->stack - 1 - address < PAGE_SIZE) ||
         address - ((unsigned long)tsk->stack + THREAD_SIZE) < PAGE_SIZE)) {
        unsigned long stack = __this_cpu_ist_top_va(DF) - sizeof(void *);
        /*
         * We're likely to be running with very little stack space
         * left.  It's plausible that we'd hit this condition but
         * double-fault even before we get this far, in which case
         * we're fine: the double-fault handler will deal with it.
         *
         * We don't want to make it all the way into the oops code
         * and then double-fault, though, because we're likely to
         * break the console driver and lose most of the stack dump.
         */
        asm volatile ("movq %[stack], %%rsp\n\t"
                  "call handle_stack_overflow\n\t"
                  "1: jmp 1b"
                  : ASM_CALL_CONSTRAINT
                  : "D" ("kernel stack overflow (page fault)"),
                "S" (regs), "d" (address),
                [stack] "rm" (stack));
        unreachable();
    }
#endif
[...]
}
```

In the above code, when a stack under/overflow is detected, the *handle_stack_overflow()* function defined in *arch/x86/kernel/traps.c*) is called:

```c
#ifdef CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
__visible void __noreturn handle_stack_overflow(const char *message,
                        struct pt_regs *regs,
                        unsigned long fault_address)
{
    printk(KERN_EMERG "BUG: stack guard page was hit at %p (stack is %p..%p)\n",
         (void *)fault_address, current->stack,
         (char *)current->stack + THREAD_SIZE - 1);
    die(message, regs, 0);

    /* Be absolutely certain we don't return. */
    panic("%s", message);
}
#endif
```

The example error message "BUG: stack guard page was hit at..." pointed out in the question comes from the above *handle_stack_overflow()* function.

**FROM YOUR EXAMPLE MODULE**

When **VMAP_STACK** is defined, the *stack_vm_area* field of the task descriptor appears and is set with the VMA address associated to the stack. From there, it is possible to grab interesting information:

```c
struct task_struct *task;
#ifdef CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
struct vm_struct *vm;
#endif // CONFIG_VMAP_STACK

task = current;

printk("\tKernel stack: 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)(task->stack));
printk("\tStack end magic: 0x%lx\n", *(unsigned long *)(task->stack));
#ifdef CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
vm = task->stack_vm_area;
printk("\tstack_vm_area->addr = 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)(vm->addr));
printk("\tstack_vm_area->nr_pages = %u\n", vm->nr_pages);
printk("\tstack_vm_area->size = %lu\n", vm->size);
#endif // CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
printk("\tLocal var in stack: 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)(&task));
```

The *nr_pages* field is the number of pages without the additional guard page. The last unsigned long at the top of the stack is set with **STACK_END_MAGIC** defined in *include/uapi/linux/magic.h* as:

```
#define STACK_END_MAGIC     0x57AC6E9D
```

**REFERENCES**:

- [Preventing stack guard-page hopping](https://lwn.net/Articles/725832/)
- [arm64: VMAP_STACK support](https://lwn.net/Articles/730997/)
- [CONFIG_VMAP_STACK: Use a virtually-mapped stack](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/VMAP_STACK.html)
- [Linux 4.9 On x86_64 To Support Vmapped Stacks](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-4.9-x86-ASM-Vmap-Stack)
- [A Decade of Linux Kernel Vulnerabilities](https://ir.library.oregonstate.edu/concern/graduate_thesis_or_dissertations/gm80j156c?locale=en)

Comment: Thank Rachid for the detailed answer. Further questions are how VMAP_STACK make guard page possible? How can I verify that guard page is guarding my stack? I did a kernel module, in fops.read() from user space, it will fetch the kernel stack pointer from task_struct, then accesses stack - PAGE_SIZE or stack + PAGE_SIZE, is this the right way to test it ? (I referred to lkdtm module).

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional information that you can grab from the task descriptor about the stack.

Comment: Awesome, the updated answer helped me much more, thanks. I am updating my kernel module accordingly.  After this is done, I may turn to study another one item about stack_guard_gap. :-)